# Adding service to QGIS

Tags: qgis, wms

I've tried to add this link as a service and it hasn't been working. I'm starting to wonder if it is even possible.

https://kyraster.ky.gov/arcgis/rest/services/ElevationServices/Ky_DEM_KYAPED_5FT_ShadedRelief/ImageServer

Comment: I'm not even seeing a layer in this service?

Comment: try https://kyraster.ky.gov/arcgis/rest/services/ElevationServices/Ky_DEM_KYAPED_5FT_ShadedRelief/ImageServer?f=jsapi for for the imagery

Comment: what should I add that as? A WCS or AGISServer? I brought this service into ArcDesktop pretty easily but i'm struggling to get it into QGIS. Here's the parent folder https://kyraster.ky.gov/arcgis/rest/services

Answer (score 3):

That's the link to the metadata page, not the service URL. To add this layer as a Web Map Service, you need to use the WMS service URL.

Get the WMS service URL by right clicking on the "WMS" in the upper left of the metadata page, and choose "copy link address". (If you're using a Mac, do whatever the Mac equivalent of a right click is. Probably command-click while eating a slice of apple and listening to iTunes.)

The WMS service URL is:
`https://kyraster.ky.gov/arcgis/services/ElevationServices/Ky_DEM_KYAPED_5FT_ShadedRelief/ImageServer/WMSServer?request=GetCapabilities&service=WMS`

In your Browser panel, right click on WMS/WMTS > new connection > paste the WMS link and add a title for the layer. Click OK, then double click on the new layer in the Browser panel to add it to your map.

It worked for me: [image]

Comment: Yes the same route I did, you posted your answer before me

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you so much!!